# Edit form in django doesn't save record after update

Tags: python, django

I have a little problem I've create a edit form to update the existing records. The form is displaying correctly, but when I click the edit button to update the records, the url redirecting me and record is not updated.
My **views.py** resposible for edit:

```
@login_required
def szczegoly_pracownik(request, id):
    link_pracownik = get_object_or_404(Cudzoziemiec, id=id)
    return render(request, 'cudzoziemiec/szczegoly_pracownik.html', {'link_pracownik': link_pracownik})

@login_required
def edycja_pracownika(request, id):
    link_pracownik = get_object_or_404(Cudzoziemiec, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        edycja_pracownika = CudzoziemiecForm(request.POST, instance=link_pracownik)
        if edycja_pracownika.is_valid():
            link_pracownik = edycja_pracownika.save(commit=False)
            link_pracownik.save()
            return render('szczegoly_pracownik', id=link_pracownik.id)
    else:
        edycja_pracownika = CudzoziemiecForm(request.user, instance=link_pracownik)
    return render(request, 'cudzoziemiec/edycja_pracownika.html', {'edycja_pracownika': edycja_pracownika})
```

The **def szczegoly_pracownika** is responsible for displaying the detail view

File **edycja_pracownika.html**

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<form action="." method="post">
    {{ edycja_pracownika.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="float-right">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Edytuj" ></p>
{% endif %}
```

and the **urls.py** responsible for detail view and edit view

```
...
    path('pracownik/<id>', edycja_pracownika, name='edycja_pracownika'),
    path('pracownik/<id>/', szczegoly_pracownik, name='szczegoly_pracownik'),
```

Maybe somebody know where is the bug?
EDIT:

**forms.py**

```
class CudzoziemiecForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cudzoziemiec
        fields = ('nazwa','imie', 'nazwisko','obywatelstwo', 'data_ur','miejsce_ur','paszport','biometria', 'data_start_pasz', 'data_koniec_pasz', 'dok_pobytowy','cel_wizy', 'data_start_pobyt', 'data_koniec_pobyt')

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):            
        super(CudzoziemiecForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['nazwa'].queryset = user.firma_set.all() 
        self.user = user

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(CudzoziemiecForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.user
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't arrive to see the real problem but a couple of things that I would try.

You are using the same almost the same url for different pages. It should not be a problem, but I see that as a possible pitfall. Why don't use something like `r'^pracownik/edytuj/$'` for the editing form? (sorry for my attempt to make a Polish url :-) ).

Maybe that can avoid possible problems and help to clarify the error.

Also when you say that:

> the url redirecting me

Do you mean you are redirected to the form again or to the detail page?

Comment: barraquito I've try this solution with for example url adding /edytuj/ on the end. After that the Django retrurn me a error about 'edytuj' is not a int...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... I meant `r'^pracownik/<id>/edytuj/$'` (I forget about the parameter in my previous message).

Comment: still doesn't work... I can't find the bug but probably it's something little :)

Comment: ok, let's try with some refactoring: after `else`, `edycja_pracownika = CudzoziemiecForm(instance=link_pracownik)` do not need `request.user` there unless you have a good reason for that. `link_pracownik = edycja_pracownika.save(commit=False)` can omit commit and remove the `link_pracownik.save()` (save will work if we arrive there). After that, instead of `return render([..])` I will do `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('szczegoly_pracownik', args=(link_pracownik.id))` because we want to show the detail page in his proper url. Don't forget the imports for HttpResponseRedirect and reverse.

Comment: barraquito could You write me by edit what I must edit in my code exacly? When after else i remove request.user the django return me a error:  __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'